# Strategy for authenticating workstation in different domain without prompt

Tags: c#, .net, windows, wcf, security

I have a .NET application that runs in the background and collects information from Windows client workstations.  It needs to send this information to a server in a different Windows domain.  The application behaves similar to a Windows service (although it is not a true Windows service) in that it runs behind the scenes without the user's knowledge.  Therefore, when my server needs to authenticate the workstations, the user cannot be prompted to enter a password or select a certificate--the authentication needs to happen without bothering them for input.

If both the workstations and the server were in the same domain, then I'd probably just use WCF with Windows Integrated Authentication aka Kerberos.  But since they're not I need a different strategy.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you establish cross-realm trust between the domains, you can use Kerberos. In this case, the minimum needed is for the realm of the server (B) to trust the realm of the clients (A). This allows foo@A to acquire a ticket for bar@B.

Comment: So suppose Forest A is high security and cannot be altered, whereas Forest B is less restricted.  If I understand you correctly, an enterprise admin for Forest B can create a trust to Forest A with no change made to the Forest A security configuration.  This would allow a client workstation that has already authenticated to A, to automatically acquire a ticket for a server in Forest B (assuming WCF using Windows Integrated auth)

Comment: A trust is implemented by a shared key between the KDCs for the two realms, so a modification to A is necessary. However, the only result is that A can issue tickets valid to B: it is B that reveals a secret to A (a key for B's ticket-granting service). It does not allow the reverse to happen, and does not reduce A's security.

Be sure to make it a "one-way trust," in Microsoft terminology.

Comment: Great, that just might be an option for us.  Thx!

Comment: You're welcome. Note that if these are in fact in different *forests* (as you wrote), then you have an added complication. Cross-realm trust between domains in the same forest works automatically. Cross-forest trust requires configuration called "top-level name translation," to tell the KDCs how to generate referrals. You can set these up with the /addtln and /removetln options of "netdom trust".